# Evenly spaced itemize in multicol

Tags: itemize, multicol

I'm looking to make test, with an undetermined number of questions of varying length. I would like the questions to have even spacing, and I also want the questions to be in two columns.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{enumitem, datatool, filecontents, tikz, pgffor, amsmath, amssymb, multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../Images/}}
\DTLsetseparator{|}

\DTLloaddb[noheader, keys={key,value}]{problems}{../Data/problems.dat}

\newcommand{\var}[1]{\DTLfetch{problems}{key}{#1}{value}}
\setlength{\voffset}{-0.75in}

\begin{document}

\hrulefill
\vspace{4mm}
\large
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{questions}

  \foreach \a in {1, ..., 20}{\question $\var{\a}$}
  \item[\vspace{\fill}]

\end{questions}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: Question 11 should be in the second column, and question 10 and 20 should be at the bottom of the page.]

[Question 11 should be in the second column, and question 10 and 20 should be at the bottom of the page.]

As you can see, in this case there are 20 elements, each being a one line question. However the questions might sometimes be longer, so I cannot just make two columns with 10 items each. I would like the questions to have the same spacing between them, except for any blank space after the last question. I've tried a few things, but I'm not that proficient with LATEX so it might be obvious.

Comment: Why don't you use the `tasks` environment in the place of `multicols`?

Comment: Isn't the tasks environment used to make horizontal lists? I just want my list to wrap at the end of the column into the next one, keeping the same spacing.

Comment: Precisely, with horizontal lists, you're sure that two consecutive questions will be horizontally aligned.

Comment: But I want the questions to list vertically, and move on to the next column after reaching the bottom of the page.

Comment: That's one possible layout, but the horizontal one is more natural for the reader.

Comment: Why are you using `\item[\vspace{\fill}]`? What happens if you just comment that out? (I can't test using your code because I don't have access to your data file.)

Comment: When I do that I get two columns of 10, but they only cover half of the page. I guess you could replace the text in `$\var{\a}$` with anything to test.

Comment: with or without that command you only cover half of the page. Did you want the `\item[vspace{\fill}]` to be **inside** the `\foreach`? Right now it is only inserting an extra "empty" item at the end of the list, so you have 21 items total, which is why the output looks odd.

Comment: I am also not clear about what you want as an output, based on your final paragraph. If question 1 is 3 lines long, and items 2-20 are all 1 line long, what is the desired output?

Comment: Putting the empty item inside the loop worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Willie Wong pointed out, I needed to place the `\item[\vspace{\fill}]` to be inside the `\foreach`.